# JPQL Query With Twice MEMBER OF And Selection Before

Tags: mysql, sql, spring, jpa, jpql

I have two User entities u1 and u2
Which have a WorkspaceMember relation by WorkspaceMember.user -> user
And a Workspace entity which contains Workspace.members -> [WorkspaceMember...]

Now what I'm trying to create is a JPQL query which firsts finds two WorkspaceMember entities by their User property and then finding the Workspaces that contain both WorkspaceMember entites.

Here is my query so far which is not working at all - I hope someone can help me on this one as i have not found any suitable example.

String sql = "SELECT wm1 FROM WorkspaceMember wm1 WHERE wm1.user = :user1 AND " +
                "SELECT wm2 FROM WorkspaceMember wm2 WHERE wm2.user = :user2 AND EXISTS " +
                "(SELECT ws1 FROM Workspace ws1 WHERE (wm1 MEMBER OF ws1.members) AND (wm2r MEMBER OF ws1.members))";

Seconf approach also not working:

String sql2 = "SELECT ws FROM Workspace ws WHERE EXISTS (SELECT wm1 FROM WorkspaceMember wm1 WHERE wm1.user = :user1 AND wm1 MEMBER OF ws.members) AND (SELECT wm2 FROM WorkspaceMember wm2 WHERE wm2.user = :user2 AND wm2 MEMBER OF ws.members)";
Thanks,

Gerrit

Comment: Found the solution myself.

Comment: Thanks for not posting the solution and keeping it to yourself.

Comment: A join with a subselect was the solution